# Lock page scroll temporarily in the middle of the long page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, so there is a webpage with a long list. In the middle of the list I'd like to lock the scrolling and later enable it again. How would this be possible, so that it would behave nicely in modern mobile browsers?

One solution I tried is to set body `position` style to fixed and the setting `top` style to the `scrollTop` value prior to the setting `position` to `fixed`. There is this thing about `position: fixed` - as soon as it is set, the page will be jumped to the top. Problem is that on iOS Safari the page is sort of flashes when you enable/disable scroll, and it also gets really laggy behaviour on Android Chrome.

Any better hints?

Update: I have a sidebar menu with list of items, and while the main page should be locked, sidebar menu should remain scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to the html-tag every time you want to look the screen. I use this method on js modals or lightboxes.

You can do this simply by adding the overflow attribute.

.

**CSS:**

```
html.-is-locked {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

.

**JS:**

Now you just have to add/remove the class with javascript:

```
//Get HTML element
var html = document.querySelector('html');

//Activate
html.classList.add('-is-locked');

//Deactivate
html.classList.remove('-is-locked');

//Toggle
html.classList.toggle('-is-locked');
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I should be more specific - I don't want to lock the whole html document, just the main tag in the body which contains the scrollable list.

Comment: This should also work with any other tag. Just edit the css/js accordingly.

Comment: Ok, tried `overflow: hidden !important;`. While this works perfectly on Desktop Chrome, on iOS Safari I can still scroll the locked background :(

Comment: Try and add `position: fixed;` to the css class, that's an iOS workaround.

Comment: EDIT: Just saw you mentioned position fixed before. The only other way on iOS would be to prevent it with javascript:

`element.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }); element.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: Ok, thanks! Thing is, as soon as you add touch event listeners, scrolling on Android Chrome becomes incredibly laggy. Which is basically another issue :/

Comment: But if you only add it on one element and remove it afterwards, is it still laggy?

Comment: Yes, basically as soon as you attach touch event listener anywhere on the page, mobile Chrome scrolling becomes laggy, even if the listener doesn't trigger anything :/

Comment: What if instead of using js you add an overlay div? It would block scrolling, since it's on top, and with a semi-transparent background-color you could create a disabled/grayed-out effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the body instead of `position:fixed`:

```
body.locked{
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

It will keep the scroll position but prevent scrolling.